# Perform a substring query in Peewee

Tags: python, sql, peewee

I'm using Python 2.7 together with Peewee. At this moment, I need to use Peewee to execute the following SQL query:

```
select 
    a,
    b,
    substring(c, 1, 3) as alias1, 
    count(substring(c, 1, 3)) as alias2
from Table
where <some where condition, not relevant here>
group by a, alias1
```

My first problem here is how to perform a substring with Peewee. I have searched the documentation and, so far, no lucky.

So, the basic question is: **How do I perform a `substring` SQL function using Peewee?** It would also be very nice if someone can give me some directions of how to perform the entire query above with Peewee.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok.

After searching and searching, I finally found it. It can be done by simply using `fn.substr`.

A reference to the function can be found [here](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#sql-functions-subqueries-and-raw-expressions). Strangely, a documentation of this same function is not present in the [`fn` documentation page](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/api.html#fn) (only the method `over` is documented there).

To answer my own question, the SQL query is going to be something like (not tested):

```
TableModel.select(
   a,
   b,
   fn.substr(c, 1, 3).alias('alias1'),
   fn.count(fn.substr(c, 1, 3)).alias('alias2')
) \
.where(<some where condition, not relevant here>) \
.group_by(a, fn.substr(c, 1, 3))
```

Hope this can help someone in the future.

Comment: The peewee fn object is magic. You can call any SQL function using it, it is syntactic sugar for generating a SQL function call. So you can do `fn.STRFTIME(..., ...)` and even nested `fn` calls.

Comment: Thanks @coleifer :). Not sure now if I misunderstood the documentation, or if the documentation didn't make it explicitly enough.