# How to search for substring in textfield in a peewee query

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, peewee

I'm trying to return results that have a particular phrase or word in a textfield of a particular item in a Sqlite database using peewee.

My current attempt has been:

```
for key in listOfKeys:
    foundPun = models.Pun.select().where(key in str(models.Pun.keywords)).get()
    click.echo('-'*10)
    click.echo(foundPun.pun)
    click.echo('-'*10)
```

Which returns the error:
`AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'clone'`

For reference, this is the Pun model:

```
class Pun(Model):
    pun = TextField()
    keywords = TextField(default="")
    tags = TextField(default="")

class Meta:
    database = db
```

Is this even the right way to go about searching for results in peewee?

Any help or pointing me in the right direction is massively appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT:
Use the query operators listed [here](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#query-operators), in particular `.contains(substr)`

ORIGINAL:

Use `fn.substr`, `fn` documentation is [here](http://peewee.readthedocs.io/en/latest/peewee/api.html#fn).

A similar question and more thorough answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35501683/perform-a-substring-query-in-peewee).

Comment: Thanks for the answer @thaavik - however i'm slightly confused how this helps solve the question. `fn.substr` allows me to get a substring of the textfield however I want to *check* if the substring `key` is in the `models.Pun.keyword` TextField. Could you please elaborate how I might do that with `fn.substr` ??

Comment: Oh, I may have misunderstood.  So you want the where clause to be similar to a SQL `like` clause? i.e. `select * from pun where keywords like '%key1%'`?

Comment: Yep - just looked that up, that's exactly what I want to achieve. I just tried `models.Pun.select(models.Pun, fn.Like('%'+key+'%'))` however that doesn't seem to be working - do you know how to correctly implement `fn.Like`?